# How to take rating value from user in a dialog box in android?

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

I had the query of how can we take the rating value from the user . I have know the onratingbarlistener . But since the code below is used while prompting user with the dialog box.
I would appreciate to hear valuable feedbacks or suggestions.

```
@Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, ImageView result)
                        {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            drivername.setTypeface(tf);
                            vehiclenumber.setTypeface(tf);
                            info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            ratingBar.setRating(4.5f);
                        }
```

> Solution :

```
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromTouch) {
   final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
   ratingBar.getRating() ;
   final float ratingBarStepSize = ratingBar.getStepSize();
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ratingBar.getRating(); //Get Rating Bar Value`

When you want to get the rating value when changed

```
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromTouch) {
   final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
   ratingBar.getRating() ;
   final float ratingBarStepSize = ratingBar.getStepSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [`RatingBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html), the [`getRating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating%28%29) method will let you get the rating value as a `float` from the user.

```
public float getRating ()
```

> Gets the current rating (number of stars filled).
>
> Returns The current rating.